# Bypass ssl certificate in alamofire request

Tags: ios, ssl, swift3, alamofire

I am having an issue when posting a request with alamofire.
My request is as follows

```
Alamofire.request(getLoginURL(), method: .post, parameters: postData, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseString { response in

        switch response.result {

        case .success:


            guard let serverResponse = response.result.value else {
                print("Could not connect to server")
                return
            }



            let decodedMessage = getDecodedMessage(serverResponse: serverResponse)
            print(decodedMessage)
            print("")

            let serverSignature = getSignature(serverMessage: serverResponse)

            let computedSignature = encodeHMAC(signatureKey: signatureKey, xml: decodedMessage)

            print(serverSignature)
            print(computedSignature)

            if computedSignature == serverSignature {
                print("they are the same")
            }else {
                print("they are not the same")
            }

            let responseCode = getReponseCode(decodedMessage: decodedMessage)
            if responseCode == 1137 {
                print("Success")
                self.goToDashBoard(decodedMessage: decodedMessage)
            }else {
                print("failure")
            }




        case.failure :
            print("request failed")
```

And i am getting this error

```
2017-04-11 12:51:01.962952+0300 PayGuard[24251:208939] [] nw_coretls_callback_handshake_message_block_invoke_3 tls_handshake_continue: [-9807]

2017-04-11 12:51:01.963 PayGuard[24251:208994] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
```

I am guessing the issue is with the SSL Certificate. Can i somehow disable the ssl verification? I included Arbitrary Loads to YES in my info.plist

Comment: hey , did you got the solutions for this problem?